# Trying to generate a sha3-512 hash in php

Tags: php, hash

Greetings members of the programming technorati. I come seeking guidance on how to generate a sha3-512 hash by using the hash_algos method, since I noticed that it can generate hashes for many of the supported hash algorithms in php 7.xx. I wish to create a simple script using hash_algos to generate a hash with a salt.  Here is the code:

```
  <?php 
  $data = 453570 ;

   $new_hash = hash_algos(sha-512);

  $sha = hash($new_hash, $data);

  echo $sha;



  //this will generate hashes and lengths of the hashes

    foreach (hash_algos() as $v) {
    $r = hash($v, $data, false);
    printf("%-12s %3d %s\n<br>", $v, strlen($r), $r);
    }


    ?>
```

Thanks in advance,

Batoe

Comment: `hash_algos()` doesn't take a parameter and just returns an array of supported hash types. Pick the one you want and use `hash()`. I don't really see what your question is here.

Comment: `SHA-512` is invalid, and `SHA512` is still SHA2. Use `SHA3-512`.

Comment: Ok, the problem I am encountering is that you can easily generate a hash with sha1, $access_hash =   sha1($access.$salt);  this is not the case with sha3. I guess since it is a new implementation, I can't just substitute the sha1 with sha3-512. I kept getting an fatal error "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sha3_256() ". Please show me the correct Syntax. thanks

Comment: Did you look at the dup?

Answer (score 0):

PHP includes dedicated functions for a limited range of hash types, so

```
$h = sha1('secret');
```

will return the SHA1 hash. This is similar to

```
$h = hash('sha1', 'secret');
```

However, for many new hash functions, no explicit function has been included. Instead, all the available hash functions are incorporated into [hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php).

You can find out which hash types are supported with [hash_algos()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-algos.php), which returns a array  of available hash types. You want to generate an SHA3-512 hash, so check that list for the hash type you need. It's supported in PHP 7.1+.

Once you've verified that the hash type is supported, use `hash()` to generate the hash:

```
$h = hash('sha3-512', 'secret');
```